# In random forest modeling in R software, if the dependent variable is more than two levels, what command should be used instead of the Roc command?

Tags: r, random-forest, roc, error-code

I am facing the error "Error in prediction(pred1[, 2], mydata$Severity) :" in the code that you see when it is executed.

[The error at the end of the code is shown in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEvrb.png)

I suppose that the error is due to the presence of the roc function, because the dependent variable in my data has more than two levels, and roc is used for the dependent variable with two levels of 0 and 1. Thank you for your guidance on what command to use instead of the roc function? And what changes should I make in the code? Thanks

Comment: What statistic you should use to measure the success of your model is not a programming question, that's a statistical matter you need decide depending on what's best for your data and the type of analysis you are trying to do. If you need statistical help, you should ask for assistance at [stats.se], not Stack Overflow. Also you should [never post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112383/roc-for-more-than-2-outcome-categories